# UITableView awkward touch issue in landscape

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I've a strange issue with UITableView, though I've many tableviews but the problem is with a particular tableview (in a viewcontroller that's the first viewcontroller of uitabbarcontroller).

In the portrait mode everything works fine. But in landscape mode, the right half of the tableview doesn't recognise any touches, and also the scrollview doesn't respond. The tableview and the subview of the cell takes there position as I needed, but the responsiveness of the touch-events is limited to the width that corresponds to that of portrait mode. beyond that the touches are not getting recognised.

And it's not all. The strange thing is that when I open another tab and come back to this starting tab, all works fine. Scrollview starts responding even when touched in the right half, the button in the extreme right of the cell works fine and right half of the textview in the middle of the cell also responds properly.

Though all of three tabs of the uitabbarcontroller have tableviews but the starting, the main, tab shows this awkward behaviour.

The behaviour is same for iPhone and iPad.

Kindly respond quickly, if anyone knows the answer to this problem.

Comment: How are your views presented? This generally happens if the transition view behind the main view is not taking the correct orientation.

Comment: Everything is arranged in storyboard, and I am also using auto-layout features.